# Python Binary Tree length

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

So I need to find the path of a binary tree that has the most unique numbers in it and return that max length given `Tree = T`  and `T.x` returns the int of the node and `T.r` and `T.`l sends the node right or left respectively.

Here is my current code:

```
def Solution(T):
head=T
arrayOfTree=[]
arrayOfTree.append(T.x)
return getDownLength(head,arrayOfTree)
def getDownLength(head,arrayOfTree):
     if head.x not in arrayOfTree:
        arrayOfTree.append(head.x)
     if head.l == None and head.r == None:
        return len(arrayOfTree)
     elif head.l == None:
        head=head.r
        return getDownLength(head,arrayOfTree)
     elif head.r == None:
        head=head.l
        return getDownLength(head,arrayOfTree)
     else:
        return max(getDownLength(head.l,arrayOfTree),getDownLength(head.r,arrayOfTree)
```

The problem I am getting here is as you use recursion `arrayOfTree` does not revert back to its original state, I tried using `del arrayOfTree[1:len(arrayOfTree)]` but I don't think that works for large input.

Any help?

Comment: Let me make a suggestion. Make a tiny sample tree, but big enough that there are multiple paths, and it has to go left and right. Make a test function which calls Solution, and see if it returns the correct answer. Fix it for that tiny tree.